# How to exclude object in response Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I do request with joining tables:

```
$categories = Model::with("translate")->get();
```

In result object I get data with `translate` for each row.

How can I exclude this from response?

Answer (score 1):

`with` is used for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), not for joining tables.

Basically with eager loading you're initially fetching all your `Models` and then  making another query to get all the `translate` instances related to your models. Then the translate models are added to your `Models`

To join the two tables you can do something like that:

```
 $categories = Model::join('translate', 'model.id', '=', 'translate.model_id')->get();
```